# How to log and show a time in a Python for/try loop?

Tags: python

Basically, I have a script that has a for/try loop, and I want it to log and show a time every time it completes one part of the loop. Example would be "Pasted with *proxy* at 10:40:30 AM EST."

Here's the code. It sends a paste to a non-popular paste website.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import requests
import string
import time


def create_paste(proxy):
    title = 'title of the paste'
    paste = 'content of the paste'

    requests.post('http://urlToPasteWebsite.co', timeout=25, data={'pastebox': paste, 'private': 0,
                                                   'syntax': 'text', 'title': title,
                                                   'paste': 'Paste'},
                                             proxies={'http': proxy})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    amount = int(raw_input('How many paste(s) do you wish to make?: '))

    proxies = [proxy.strip() for proxy in open('proxies.txt', 'r')]
    random.shuffle(proxies)

    for _ in range(amount):
        proxy = random.choice(proxies)
        try:
            create_paste(proxy)
            print('Pasted with %s.' % proxy)
        except:
            print('Something went wrong with %s.' % proxy)
```

Comment: I don't see a while loop anywhere

Comment: @Haidro He used for as while loop. :)

Comment: Updated, apologies! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here many answer, but you can use [time module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) for get time and pretty print it:

```
import time
current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %p %Z', time.localtime())
print 'Now is %s' % current_time
```

For me it have printed below:

```
Now is 07:52:53 AM EEST
```

Here `strftime()` is functuion for customizable output, `localtime()` for get current timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

```
import logger
import datetime
```

After create_paste function, add this line

```
logger.debug(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm relatively new to Python. Where exactly would I put 'logger.debug(datetime.datetime.now())' in my script to make it show up?

Comment: In fact, you don't need to use `datetime`. `logger` has a builtin timer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the datetime module. I'm a bit confused of where you're trying to put this, since I don't see any `while` loop, but I'll show you how to do it anyway:

You can use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now.strftime('%H:%M:%s %p %Z')
```

---

Integrated in your code, I guess you want it at:

```
for _ in range(amount):
    proxy = random.choice(proxies)
    right_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%s %p %Z')
    try:
        create_paste(proxy)
        print('Pasted with %s at %s.' % (proxy, right_now))
    except:
        print('Something went wrong with %s at %s.' % (proxy, right_now))
```

Don't forget to `import datetime` ;)

Comment: Where exactly would I put this to make the example that I used in the original post to show up? Sorry for asking you to spoonfeed me, but I'm relatively new to Python.

Comment: @BrandonJackson Make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces

Comment: 'NameError: name 'now' is not defined' in paste print?

Comment: @BrandonJackson Ah sorry, that was an error in my part. Looks like BurhanKhalid fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for 'except:' now, lol. Also, thanks BurhanKhalid!

Comment: @BrandonJackson Try again (copy/paste the code from my answer again). I recently just edited it because I found another error. Sorry for the whole hassle!

Comment: Getting a value error for right_now. I copied and pasted what you used in your post, here's what my script looks like. http://pastie.org/8337911 Also, I'm using 2.7.5 if that's relevant.